# TELEPHONY_SERVICE constant not recognised in one class, but is in another

Tags: java, android

This feels very much like another case of not seeing the forest for the trees.

I've written a small (non-extending) class for my app that, for now, only contains the one method to scrape a supplied URL and return a string. I was hoping to include the Device ID on the end of the query string, so added the following lines:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;
...
TelephonyManager m_tmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

However, the TELEPHONY_SERVICE constant "cannot be resolved to a variable", according to Eclipse. If I copy and paste these lines into another class in the package (all the other classes are activities, at the moment, which may have something to do with it?), it all works fine.

What's the massively obvious thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

TELEPHONY_SERVICE is a member of the Context class which is the super class of the Activity class. So this constant is available only in Activity or Context sub-classes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#TELEPHONY_SERVICE

You can access the same as Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE

Comment: Yet somehow `getSystemService()` itself works, without a reference to `Context`? Odd!

Comment: @Richard, if this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding a little correction in your code.

Just change:

```
TelephonyManager m_tmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

with:

```
 TelephonyManager m_tmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have static imported the constant. Please find the line which begins with `import static` and copy it to another class. More [here](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060211/index.html).

Comment: Can't find a single import static anywhere in the project, sorry :<

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
import android.content.Context;
```

by

```
import static android.content.Context.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```